# locationmanager does not update the coordinate

Tags: swift, swift3

I'm just trying a map example on Xcode with Swift 3. I managed to put a map view on the screen and running the project on the simulator. I can see that the coordinate moves when I change the simulated location as expected.

However I cannot print the current coordinate. I did put a button on the screen such that when it is clicked, the coordinate given by the locationmanager is supposed to be printed in Xcode terminal. I've included my code below, the button action showCoordinates is supposed to print the current coordinate.

```
import UIKit
import MapKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

let locationManager = CLLocationManager()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

@IBOutlet weak var myLattitude: UILabel!  // These are the labels that will show the coordinate on the screen when pressed.
@IBOutlet weak var myLongitude: UILabel!

@IBAction func showCoordinates(_ sender: AnyObject) {

    let myCoordinate = locationManager.location?.coordinate
    print(myCoordinate) // This does not work as expected
}


func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
    guard status == .authorizedWhenInUse  else {
        print("Location not enabled")
        return
    }

    print("Location allowed.")
    mapView.showsUserLocation = true
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

When I run this in the simulator and change the simulated coordinate, the blue point in the map moves fine but the showCoordinate button prints only the first location. Even if the location changes, it prints the first location. How can I make that function properly?

Comment: Is `ocationManager(_ manager:didUpdateLocations:)` called?

Comment: Thanks. No I didn't add that. Where can I put it?

Answer (score 0):

Call your `showCoordinates(_ sender: AnyObject)` function from your `ViewController`'s `func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation])`

Like this:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    showCoordinates(self)
}
```

Alternatively you can input it directly in your `didUpdateLocations` callback, like this:

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    let myCoordinate = locationManager.location?.coordinate
    print(myCoordinate)
}
```

But delegating is a better approach, because if you want to change the format, or do some additional work instead of simply printing coordinates, you'd only have to change one function. If you do not use delegation, you'd end up with two independent functions that you have to maintain and update separately, even though they do the same thing.

Comment: Thanks mate, I got the idea.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using mapkit, then use

> mapview.userlocation

to print. otherwise implement location manager delegates